# What's the usual way to setup a React and Express webApp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on a project that requires developing a SPA using React, Node and Express. I understand Node/Express can serve static files and so my initial thought was I will write a react app and serve it via Express server. 
But my Node/Express server also has other roles like, connecting with other microservices and fetch data, which will eventually passed to the UI controlled by react SPA.Sort of a controller! I am also planning to use Graphql instead of Rest.

Will the approach of using the Express server to do both serving the SPA and as a controller has any complication, or should I separate them as two different webapps.

I couldn't find many usecases  for my first approach (keeping both together),but I could see that splitting them as  two,like here https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/full-stack-react-graphql-tutorial-582ac8d24e3b

Any suggestions on what is the right approach?
Thanks

Comment: typically, you'd use something like nginx to serve the static files in a production environment.

Answer (score -1):

If you just wanna serve a static file you can use Amazon S3 bucket to serve your React app and throw a a CDN in front of it for optimal load times.

Its nice to keep the separated but it also depends on the size and scope of the project. If you wanna expand it later it might hurt that your API is also serving the app and all its assets.

Where as separating them will split the load from actual API usage and static asset requests (images, index.html ect...).